# Mobile Data Tables and Mobile Screen Readers

Tags: html, mobile, datatable

Does anyone know any html code for simple data table that can be read by Chrome, FireFox (nightly) and Safari? I have my mobile web page for HTML 5 and the table code can only be read by two of them. I have tried defining the roles for row\column headers, grid and gridcell. I tried using aria-lableby with ids. I tried basic  and scope and headers\id and nothing really works. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: So are you using pure HTML, <table>, or are you using some other technology to produce a "datatable"?

Comment: I'm using straight HTML, hand coded.

Comment: Let's see your HTML code for creating the table then.